# Show all View Controllers in Main.Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently, in Main.Storyboard, a friend of mine managed to open up a side bar listing all view controllers so that he could easily drag buttons into these controllers without worrying about any side issues. Can anyone direct me as to how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click the button left-bottom of storyboard editor window:

[image]